# "network request failed..." when trying to use metaboss

Tags: solana-program, decode

I installed metaboss on my Ubuntu server using this: `bash <(curl -sSf https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samuelvanderwaal/metaboss/main/scripts/install.sh)`.

When I run `metaboss decode mint -a xxxxxxxxxxxx` I get an error: `Error: network request failed after three attempts: ensure you used a valid address and check the state of the Solana cluster`.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error suggests that you have to check the RPC Url and Check the cluster you are connected to :

```
solana config get
```

If you are connected to wrong cluster set that using :

```
solana config set --url <rpc url>
```

Comment: I didn't have solana cli tools installed, after doing that worked. Thanks!

Comment: also in metaboss i used the `-r` flag to set the rpc

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this error because i used this syntax:

```
metaboss *--rpc <MyRPC url>* decode mint <Adress>
```

but i finaly did solana config set --url  and used again the syntax above whithout change.
That worked but without the --rpc, like that:

```
metaboss decode mint <Adress>
```